# Call helpers functions from other template related functions

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

From **Template.myTemplate.rendered** function (or from other template functions), I want to call other util function. Not sure how to do it in Meteor way.

I tried

```
 Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){
   console.log("chat Interface rendered");
   Template.myTemplate.__helpers.get('someFunction');
 };


 Template.myTemplate.helpers({
   'isEditable': function () {
     return Session.get('editable');
   },
   'someFunction':function () {
     console.log("someFunctionis called");
     //More stuff here

   }
});
```

This did not work as expected. Is there any standard way of doing it?

Comment: You can create a global function and call it on different templates

Comment: Could you provide some more context for this question? I think you can use session variables to toggle the disable state of a button instead of what you are trying to do.

Comment: How we know if you don't provide your `other util function`

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make any sense.

If you want the button to be disabled on load, you should probably just put the "disabled" property directly on the HTML.

Are you trying to disable a button once the "chat Interface is rendered"? Or enable it?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you are misusing [template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers). In general, they are used to get data into templates and not to control UI elements.

As a result, I recommend to create a regular JavaScript function and subsequently call it inside your `onRendered` callback:

```
function disableChatBtn() {
  console.log("disableChatBtn is called");
  $('#btn-chat').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

**Please note:** `Template.myTemplate.rendered` is deprecated in Meteor version 1.0.4.2 (and later), use **[`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)** instead.

For example:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  console.log("chat Interface rendered");
  disableChatBtn();
});
```

Comment: If you want to toggle the button state, it makes sense to use, say, Session variable for that in template helpers and events. I definitely wouldn't rule out that option.

Comment: @durrr : See this is very simple example where toggling the button, WHat if there is other stuffs to do ? , M asking the concept, the way..

Comment: @monda This comment was about controlling UI elements. For your question I already suggested creating a global function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a meteor method and use it everywhere in your code. You can also call methods from other methods.

```
Meteor.methods({
  someMethod: function (param) {
    //do stuff
  }
});

var result = Meteor.call('someMethod', param);
```